# How can I align text in the center of a div without using height, line height and padding?

Tags: html, css

How can I align text in the center of a div without using height, line height and padding?

```
<div id="slot">
   <p id="element">100 </p>
</div>

#slot {
    width: 70px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    background-color: #00ffee;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#element {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The text-align is a property to be set on the parent really, so put it in the #slot css

http://jsfiddle.net/uFpCL/

```
#slot {
    width: 70px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    background-color: #00ffee;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Mark the answer as 'the answer' that was most helpful to you (with the green tick)

Answer (score 2):

I supose that you want to align vertically right? I don't know if I've understood well what you are asking, but I've done this.

HTML

```
<div id="slot"><p id="element">100 </p></div>
```

CSS

```
#slot {
    width: 70px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    background-color: #00ffee;
    display:table;
    height:150px;
    text-align: center;
}

#element {    
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

I only added three lines in CSS. `display:table`  for the parent and `display:table-cell` for the child. Finally I added `vertical-align: middle` to display the text on the middle if the height increments, and put `text-align:center` at container div.

[Here you have an example](http://jsfiddle.net/newpatriks/A7S8h/)

Comment: you can also specific line-height as big as the parent's height to vertically center the text, but it only works for single-line text only

Answer (score 2):

If you want the content of the *#element* tag to be centered, take @newpatriks' approach. But if you want the *#element* to be in the middle of the *#slot* element, you could add this css to the *#slot* element:

```
#slot {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

This way, all children of *#slot* will be centered in there.

http://jsfiddle.net/A7S8h/3/

Answer (score 1):

I think you should explore the flexbox. Its supposed to be the Holy Grail of layouts using css. A quick tutorial:

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Just want to add, that the support for this method is quite thin.

Comment: The flexbox spec has just gone stable. Now its up to rendering engines to adopt it. And that's not gonna take long.

Answer (score 0):

Use margin to adjust your text

```
 #slot {
  margin:auto;
    width: 70px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    background-color: #00ffee;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
}
```

it works fine now try ..

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A7S8h/2/)

Answer (score 0):

I see this is pretty outdated question, but in case someone still looking for answer, here is the simple solution for 2022:

just set class to element .centerInsideDiv and in css:

```
.centerInsideDiv {
  display: grid;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
```

Hope i helped somebody today!